# Problems with printing data into TableView (Swift)

Tags: arrays, json, swift, tableview

I've function that makes http-request and save result into 2 arrays

Then I'm calling `tableViewObejct.reloadData()` to display result into `tableView`. But if I do the second after first function - nothing happens. I'have to call my function into `viewDidLoad`, then I've a button where I'm doing `reloadData()` and only after that I can see my data in `tableView`.

**Function**:

```
func refreshData(){
     self.myData.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
     self.ids.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
     httpGet("https://money.yandex.ru/api/categories-list") { result in
         let json=JSON(data: result)
         println(json[0]["subs"].count)
         for var i=0; i<json.count; ++i {
             self.myData.append(json[i]["title"].stringValue)
             self.ids.append("")
             for var g=0; g<json[i]["subs"].count;++g {
                 self.myData.append("    "+json[i]["subs"][g]["title"].stringValue)
                 self.ids.append(json[i]["subs"][g]["id"].stringValue)
             }
         }
         println(self.myData.count)
         println(self.ids.count)
     }
}
```

`myData` is global public string array, `ids` - too

Functions for `tableView`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
     return myData.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath
indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
     let cell:UITableViewCell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "mycell")
     cell.textLabel!.text = myData[indexPath.row]
     return cell
}
```

So the problem that I need to cal refreshData-function and see result in `tableView` at the same time, just by `viewDidLoad` or clicking a button. Why I have to separate these doings to see array-data in `tableView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reload your tableView this way when you get your data from server:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

and you code will be like this:

```
func refreshData(){
    self.myData.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.ids.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    httpGet("https://money.yandex.ru/api/categories-list") { result in
        let json=JSON(data: result)
        println(json[0]["subs"].count)
        for var i=0; i<json.count; ++i {
            self.myData.append(json[i]["title"].stringValue)
            self.ids.append("")
            for var g=0; g<json[i]["subs"].count;++g {
                self.myData.append("    "+json[i]["subs"][g]["title"].stringValue)
                self.ids.append(json[i]["subs"][g]["id"].stringValue)
            }
        }
        println(self.myData.count)
        println(self.ids.count)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

It was a little hard to understand the question, but what I think is happening is that at the time you are calling `tableView.reloadData()`, your `GET` request has not completed. Now I do not know the internal implementation of the `httpGet` function, but I will assume that it is asynchronous. This means that that your tableview is reading data before the request is completed.